# Link Blocked in Facebook

Tags: facebook

We believe the link you are trying to visit is malicious. For your safety, we have blocked it.here is the screenshot attached! [image]

Answer (score 0):

Advertising links are blocked by Facebook. Facebook fetches the link page and if it found the issue it blocks the page.
adf.ly is one example of blocked link

Comment: but how cold we unblock this ?

Comment: You can short URL using google service https://goo.gl/ and Unblock The Blocked URL
It will not be considered as spam.